# Laravel-MYSQL Search through for values in database and then display them

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a textbox that I'm trying to use to search through the database, What I'm trying to achieve is when I type in a date of birth(e.g 14/06/1996) into the textbox(searchdob)  it will display the users that have this date of birth value in the database. I've tried use my AppointmentController to do the where conditions so the foreach loop is kept tidier.

Error is: Non-static method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::get() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

AppointmentController

```
function addAppointment()
{
    $doctors = Doctor::all();
    $search = Request::get('searchdob');
    $users = User::where('role',  '=',  1)
                   ->where('dateofbirth', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                   ->get();

    return view('appointment/addappointmentform',['users'=>$users],['doctors'=>$doctors]);
}
```

addappointment.blade

```
<form>
    Insert Patients date of birth
    <input
    type="text"
    name="searchdob"
    id="searchdob"
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        }"
    maxlength="10"
></form>


    <fieldset>
<legend>Select the Patient</legend> 
@foreach($users as $user)
    <div>
        <label for="dirBtn{{$user->id}}">
        <input id="dirBtn{{$user->id}}" type="radio" name="user" value="{{$user->id}}">
        {{$user->firstname}}
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$search = request('searchdob');
```

Comment: Thats fixed that problem thanks, I've now realised my foreach loop is wrong, instead of displaying users with the inserted date of birth, it's getting every user in the database, should I remove the where statement in the controller and try put something similar into the foreach loop?

Comment: If you want to filter users by date of birth, you should add this column to the `$dates` model property and do something like this `->whereDate('dateofbirth', Carbon::parse(request('searchdob')))`

Comment: Sorry...I'm a bit confused, I don't have a dates model, I have a User model, shall I put it there?

Comment: `$dates` property in the model. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators